# Help with Authorize(Roles=)] MVC 3 Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

I am having problems with Authorize attribute in MVC 3 with Windows Authentication.  When I decorate a controller with the [Authorize] attribute a specify a role, the Authorization always returns false when I know the user is a member of the role I specified. Am I missing something? Does anybody have some examples of how they used [Authorize] attribute in MVC 3 with Windows Authentication?  Thanks for the help......

Comment: If you change the role to "YOURPCNAME\Admin" does it work? Did you set the role provider in the web.config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]

Should be enough

Comment: I had to use GetUserInRoles() to retrieve specific role names ...thanks for the response..